# $_POST variable is empty when code is executed using Telegram webhook

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am creating a Telegram Bot using PHP. I have set the webhook to "https://example.com/bot.php". As you can see below, I used *echo* to run a script that creates HTML form. After being created, the form then is submitted automatically and I get variables using POST method.

```
echo "<script>
        document.write('<form method=\"post\" action=\"\" id=\"myForm\">');
        document.write('<textarea name=\"price\">' + 12345 + '</textarea><br>');
        document.write('<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"></form>');
      </script>";

if (!isset($_POST['price']) ) {
  echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"myForm\").submit();</script>";
}

$price = $_POST['price'];
```

If I run `"bot.php`" manually (using the URL), the code works just fine. However, when I send the commands in a Telegram bot, *`$_POST['price']`* returns `empty`.
To check that I sent *`isset($_POST['price'])`* as a message to the bot, and I received `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know the JS is client-side and that's why it works on your web browser and it doesn't work on Bot request because the bots can't run JavaScript.